# How can I fetch one column with conditons in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-rest-framework

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='255')
date = models.DateField()
```

Hello .

This is my model.I want to fetch the data for "limit" and "where id = 5" for example. How can I do that ?  I want to use it as Integer. not Queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one instance with id = 5 (it should be), then you can get value of limit using:

```
YourModel.objects.get(id=5).limit
```

You can read more about making queries here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: thanks for your help but  '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'QuerySet'. It returns as a queryset. I want to just Integer.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try YourModel.objects.get(id=5).limit

Comment: Its done ! I dont know how can I thank you !! Really Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :D You can mark my answer as accepted and we are even :D